# Difference between 'similar looking' Morse functions

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, low-dimensional-topology, morse-theory

Let's say $f$ and $g$ are two Morse functions on same manifold $M$, and have same domain, same range, same critical points, same critical values at those points and same index at those critical points. Then is there a relation between $f$ and $g$? Are those two related in any way?
Any intuition, reference will be helpful.

Comment: Their stable/unstable manifolds can be still quite different. In particular, you could get non-isotopic handle decompositions.

Comment: @MoisheCohen And it would be a great answer if you could have added what is a complete invariant for Morse functions :)

Comment: I see what you're pointing at @MoisheCohen, thank you.